# Tailwind not loading when I use middleware to make my user auth system

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, middleware

The error is :

```
 http://localhost:3000/signup was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.
```

I've noticed an issue where the CSS fails to load on the signup page when I implement this middleware code, yet it loads without issue on the main page. Intriguingly, the presence of a token seems to somehow enable the CSS to load correctly:

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const isLoggedin = cookies().get("isLoggedin");
  if (
    !isLoggedin &&
    request.nextUrl.pathname !== "/signup"
  ) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/signup", request.url));
  }
  if (
    isLoggedin &&
    request.nextUrl.pathname == "/signup" 
  ) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", request.url));
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

I attempted to configure the settings, but unfortunately, it didn't seem to meet my requirements, or at least that's my understanding based on the unsuccessful attempt. My goal is to ensure that when a user is logged in, they can exclusively access pages designed for authenticated users. Conversely, for users who are not logged in, I intend to restrict access to pages designated for non-logged-in users.

Comment: Found a solution! All i did was to use 
` const acceptHeader = request.headers.get("accept");`
and to inlcude it in every if like `  if (
    !isLoggedin &&
    request.nextUrl.pathname !== "/signup" &&
    acceptHeader &&
    acceptHeader.includes("text/html")
  )`

It seems to work,but I still wanna know if there is a better way to fix that issue